# How can I had a cron-job Command using php artisan?

Tags: php, laravel, cron, laravel-artisan

I have some problems with php artisan cron.

Currently, the tasks is in App\Console\Commands\task1.php
and the cron is defined in App\Console\Kernel.php

The problem is: the task is not launched.

So I tried to create a new task, using the command line:
`php path/to/artisan make:command task2`

and a file is created, but in App\Commands instead of App\Console\Commands.

And when trying to list existing cron task with `artisan list`, I only get:
`vendor:publish         Publish any publishable assets from vendor packages`

Where should I put my Commands?
And where should be the Kernel file?

Currently, Kernel.php is:

```php
<?php namespace App\Console;

use App\Commands\Task2;
use App\Console\Commands\Task1;
use Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel as ConsoleKernel;

class Kernel extends ConsoleKernel {

    protected $commands = [
        Task1::class,
        Task2::class,
    ];

    protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
        $schedule->command('task1')->daily();
        $schedule->command(Task2::class)->daily();
    }

}
```

Task1, the one created using command line, in App\Commands folder:

```php
<?php namespace App\Commands;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Bus\SelfHandling;

class Task1 extends Command implements SelfHandling {

    protected $name = 'task1';

    protected $description = 'Task1 test ';

    public function handle()
    {}
}
```

Task2, in App\Console\Commands folder:

```php
<?php namespace App\Console\Commands;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;

class Task2 extends Command {

    protected $name = 'task2';

    protected $description = 'task 2 test';

    public function handle()
    {}
}
```

Comment: Isn't the problem `taks1` instead of `task1`

Comment: no, real names are not 'task1' nor 'task2', but I doubled check and there is no typo, unfortunately.

Comment: please post `App\Console\Commands\Task1;` and `App\Commands\Task2;` classes as well

Comment: also, there are only 5 asterisks, you have 6

Comment: I added the tasks (without handle method).

Comment: I also change the cron with ->daily, but it's not working.

Answer (score 2):

You need `$signature` instead of `$name`

```
<?php namespace App\Commands;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Bus\SelfHandling;

class Task1 extends Command implements SelfHandling {

    protected $signature = 'task1';

    protected $description = 'Task1 test ';

    public function handle()
    {}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change in Kernel.php for

```
$schedule->command('task2')->daily();
```

remove

```
use App\Commands\Task2;
use App\Console\Commands\Task1;
```

Change

```
protected $commands = [
    Console\Commands\Task1::class,
    Commands\Task2::class,
];
```

And add `$signature` in yours commands

Use `artisan make:console` (old Laravel)